# Getting "HandshakeError: Invalid response status: 404 Not Found" while connecting python code to gephi

Tags: python, gephi

I'm trying to create a graph using Python code. I need it to be visualized in gephi.

I tried this python code:

```py
from gephistreamer import graph
from gephistreamer import streamer
stream = streamer.Streamer(streamer.GephiWS())
node_a = graph.Node("A",custom_property=1)
node_b = graph.Node("B")
node_b.property['custom_property']=2
stream.add_node(node_a,node_b)
edge_ab = graph.Edge(node_a,node_b,custom_property="hello")
stream.add_edge(edge_ab)
```

My gephi Graph streaming plugin is active as master. When I run the python code, an error occurs like this:

```
HandshakeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7856b7437ce1> in <module>()
      1 from gephistreamer import graph
      2 from gephistreamer import streamer
----> 3 stream = streamer.Streamer(streamer.GephiWS())
      4 
      5 # Create a node with a custom_property

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gephistreamer/streamer.pyc in __init__(self, hostname, port, workspace)
    113         self.workspace = workspace
    114         self.websocket = self.Client(self._generate_url())
--> 115         self.websocket.connect()
    116     def _generate_url(self):
    117         return "ws://{hostname}:{port}/{workspace}?operation=updateGraph".format(hostname=self.hostname,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ws4py/client/__init__.pyc in connect(self)
    235 
    236         try:
--> 237             self.process_response_line(response_line)
    238             self.protocols, self.extensions = self.process_handshake_header(headers)
    239         except HandshakeError:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ws4py/client/__init__.pyc in process_response_line(self, response_line)
    300         protocol, code, status = response_line.split(b' ', 2)
    301         if code != b'101':
--> 302             raise HandshakeError("Invalid response status: %s %s" % (code, status))
    303 
    304     def process_handshake_header(self, headers):

HandshakeError: Invalid response status: 404 Not Found
```

Can anyone please help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I just read your question was looking for a solution as well. Some hints which helped me a lot to get it running:

1. Specify the connection explicit: `streamer.GephiWS(hostname="localhost", port=8080, workspace="workspace0")`
2. the workspace title you should rename in Gephi, avoiding uppercase characteres and spaces. All uppercase characters have to be transformed in python to lowercase ones
3. Test in Browser whether you can reach `http://localhost:8080/workspace0`
4. I messed up a bit with the plugin.. I noticed that it not really restarts to effect settings. I always closed the project and started the Master server new
5. I changed port to something else then `8080`